# dirichlet problem in the heisenberg group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, elliptic-pde, sub-riemannian-geometry, heisenberg-groups

Good morning everybody.

I was looking just for a quick reference to know whether the Dirichlet problem has a solution in the Heisenberg group, that is $\mathbb R^3$ endowed with coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and an horizontal distribution spanned by $X=\partial_x-\frac y2\partial_z$ and $Y=\partial_y+\frac x2 \partial_z$.

I don't look for representation formulas, rather to the standard existence results like harnack maximum principles, etc..

Many thanks in advance.

Regards, Guido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at:

> A. Bonfiglioli, E. Lanconelli, F. Uguzzoni.  *Stratified Lie Groups
>   and Potential Theory
>   for their Sub-Laplacians*.  Springer, 2007.  [DOI 10.1007/978-3-540-71897-0](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-71897-0)

This book is always my first reference for this sort of general theory.  In Section 7.1 you can find a theorem giving sufficient conditions on an open set $U$ for the Dirichlet problem $Lu=0$ on $U$, $u = \varphi$ on $\partial U$, to be solvable (here I presume you want $L = X^2 + Y^2$ to be the usual sub-Laplacian); e.g. Proposition 7.1.5.  The book has a lot more material on the potential theory of $L$ as well.  And in Chapter 5 you can find a development of Harnack inequalities, maximum principles, mean value theorems, etc, for functions (sub-)harmonic with respect to $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about the inhomogeneous problem $Lu=f$ on $U$?